# Mysql Getting the date of the second of the next month

Tags: mysql, date

Hi Everyone and Thank You for your help in advance. I have a query and I want to compare a date to be less or equal to the second of the next month. I am trying to put this in a view in MySQL. For example today is 2014/07/29 and I want the query to check the 2014/08/02.

Thank You

Comment: OK. Seems simple enough. What stops you?

Comment: Here is a list of all the [**Date and Time Functions**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

Comment: Date of the second will always be the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it as:

```
rc.cov_date <= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 MONTH, %Y-%m-02)
```